Integrating t265 into an existing urdf
I am developing a SLAM system using a 2D Lidar and some other sensors. I am using slam_toolbox to create the map->odom_frame tf, but I have a lot of doubts and issues about it.
I am using a t265 camera for visual odometry, which is giving me the following tf tree:

There are two issues here that I am not 100% sure are solved:

The odometry is published in an odometry message, with this header:

header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1716542824
    nanosec: 996115712
  frame_id: odom_frame
child_frame_id: camera_pose_frame
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -0.0022404827177524567
      ...


If I enable the camera to publish the tf, that creates an odom_frame frame (I have to fix the naming) whose child is camera_pose_frame. Nothing wrong with that other than the fact that the camera_pose_frame is the child to a frame of the global robot urdf file I have, so there exists a base_link->camera_attachment_frame->camera_pose_frame static transform. This breaks every frame being children to just one so what I do is tell the camera to not publish the transform, and I have a node that combines the base_link->camera_pose_frame with the information from the odom_frame message to publish dynamically the odom_frame -> base_link transform. This I am fairly certain is the right thing to do, and I end up with something like this:

There should be a map->odom_frame as well but slam_toolbox did not have the time to start. So the question here is: Is this the right way of doing it? Creating the tf myself from and to those frames.

The t265 has an IMU inside, I assume it's  using it to create a good odometry, but still I would like to combine it with another IMU and a GPS in the future. The message published by the camera is:

header:
 stamp:
   sec: 1716544946
   nanosec: 871385600
 frame_id: camera_imu_optical_frame
orientation:


camera_imu_optical_frame does not exist on the tf tree published by the camera. I have read that I have to use the imu_filter_madgwick. The IMU has only gyro + accel, no magnetic data, so I am not sure it is needed. In any case, I am using it to create the link odom_frame->camera_imu_optical_frame. Is this the good link to create? Why? When I visualize it on RVIZ the camera_imu_optical_frame rotates correctly (or so I think) but right on the odometry_frame frame with no translation. The rest of the tf tree rotates and translates well and I can see it relating to the real world.
Is there any glaring issue with this setup?
